# PHP rethrow exception from constructor

Tags: php, oop, exception

Just wanted to know if this is a common practice.  Basically the constructor is calling some initialization functions that throw on failure. My thinking is it makes sense just to rethrow the exception right back to where the object is being created since that's where actual output is being sent.

Is this "best practice" for this kind of situation? Or is there a more standard way to do this?

```
<?php
  class a {   
        private $x;
        private $y;
        function __construct($filename) {
             try {
                 $this->x = $this->functionThatMightThrowException($filename);
                 $this->y = $this->doSomethingElseThatMightThrow();
             }
             catch(InvalidArgumentException $e) {
                  throw $e;    //is this a good practice or not???
             }
             catch(Exception $e) {
                  throw $e;    //again
             }
         }

         //rest of class definition
    }

  // then somewhere else where the object is created and output is being sent
  $fn = "blah.txt";
  try {
    $a = new a($fn);
  }
  catch (InvalidArgumentException $e) {
     //actually handle here -- send error message back etc
  } 
  catch (Exception $e) {
     //etc
  }
?>
```

Comment: Why are you catching it in the first place if you are just going to rethrow it???

Comment: I'd say that this is superfluous. Don't worry. Let them pop through uncatched, no need to re-throw them.

Comment: If you don't catch a particular exception, it'll simply trickle back up the execution chain. catching and re-throwing the same exception is generally pointless. normally you only catch the ones you actually WANT to handle, and let the rest trickle upstairs for handling elsewhere. It's like a buffet: if you don't want to eat something, then don't put it on your plate in the first place.

Comment: If you're not going to do anything other than re-throw it then don't even bother catching it.

Comment: The only reason you would want to catch and re-throw is if you are rethrowing a different type of exception or you are manipulating the contents of the exception in some way (i.e. adding a human readable error message)

Comment: OK, I think I understand.  Try/Catching it once at the top is sufficent and the try in constructor is not necessary unless I'm adding some other handling code there.  Thanks all

Comment: I seriously question the judgement of those who voted to close this question.   I get that the idea was wrong in the question, but the whole *point* of the question was whether or not the exception  needed to be rethrown or if it happened automatically.   It's preposterous to say the question did not demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved.  Certainly more than adequate example code and explanation was provided -- maybe wrong, but isn't that the whole reason for asking?

Are you moderators suggesting we only post questions where we already know the answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's see only this part of code:

```
         try {
             $this->x = $this->functionThatMightThrowException($filename);
             $this->y = $this->doSomethingElseThatMightThrow();
         }
         catch(InvalidArgumentException $e) {
              throw $e;    //is this a good practice or not???
         }
         catch(Exception $e) {
              throw $e;    //again
         }
```

Because `InvalidArgumentException` is as well an `Exception` this is a typical case of code-duplication and per-se can be reduced to:

```
         try {
             $this->x = $this->functionThatMightThrowException($filename);
             $this->y = $this->doSomethingElseThatMightThrow();
         }
         catch(Exception $e) {
              throw $e;    //again
         }
```

Now the line where you ask if that is good practice or not is gone. So I guess even with this purely systematic approach to remove duplicate code, the question could be answered: No, that was not good practice. That was code-duplication.

Next to that - as already commented - re-throwing an exception has no value. So the code can be reduced even to:

```
         $this->x = $this->functionThatMightThrowException($filename);
         $this->y = $this->doSomethingElseThatMightThrow();
```

So I hope this helps. The code does exactly the same as before, no difference, just less code which is always welcome.

Comment: So you're saying the try/catch block around the "$A = new a($fn);" is sufficient to catch the exception? No need for extra try block in constructor because exception will find its way back there anyway?

Comment: well, define *suffice*, but reading how exceptions generally work in PHP http://php.net/language.exceptions leads basically to such a conclusion, yes.

Comment: I should mention the multiple catch blocks are there because the functions throw InvalidArgumentException for a specific case and that needs to be handled differently than some other random possibility.